# How can I efficiently return rows for a WHERE condition with multiple sets of values to match?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with the following columns:

```
id, name, surname
```

I have the following sql query:

```
SELECT `id` from `table` WHERE name = 'John' AND surname = 'Smith';
```

As I have a list of names and surnames and I'd like to check if they are present in the table or not I would like to make a single query and return the id (if there is a match for both name and surname of a set) or an empty id (or zero) to indicate there is no match for the combination of name and surname.

So what I have is basically this:

```
SELECT `id` from `table` WHERE name = 'John' AND surname = 'Smith';
SELECT `id` from `table` WHERE name = 'Claudia' AND surname = 'Janssen';
SELECT `id` from `table` WHERE name = 'Eduart' AND surname = 'Allen';
SELECT `id` from `table` WHERE name = 'Don' AND surname = 'Diablo';
SELECT `id` from `table` WHERE name = 'Esther' AND surname = 'Smith';
```

(a large number of those queries)

I think the statement IN does not work because it will also return an id if someone with the same name and another person with the same surname was found in the table. It is important that the combination is found.

My question is: **How can I efficiently execute a mysql query as stipulated with the 5 single queries above?**

Comment: Are you sure that you cannot identify any errors here?

Comment: You have incorrect SQL queries.

Comment: Yeah, there were some 'beauty' mistakes, edited them.

Comment: Quotes are for creating strings. If you want to escape the column and table names you should use backticks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `OR`:

```
SELECT id
FROM table
WHERE (name = 'John' and surname 'Smith')
OR (name = 'Claudia' and surname 'Janssen')
OR (name = 'Eduart' and surname 'Allen')
...
```

Make sure you use the parentheses, because of the precedence between `AND` and `OR`.

You could also do it using `UNION`, which may be more efficient if you have indexes on the `name` and `surname` columns, because the `OR` condition may not use them.

```
SELECT id from table WHERE name = 'John' and surname 'Smith'
UNION
SELECT id from table WHERE name = 'Claudia' and surname 'Janssen'
UNION
SELECT id from table WHERE name = 'Eduart' and surname 'Allen'
UNION
...
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I added iffnull in front of each select statement to whether a result was found or not.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you were looking for?

```
SELECT `id` 
FROM   `table` 
WHERE  (`name` = 'John' AND `surname` = 'Smith') 
        OR (`name` = 'Claudia' AND `surname` = 'Janssen') 
        OR (`name` = 'Eduart' AND `surname` = 'Allen') 
        OR (`name` = 'Don' AND `surname` = 'Diablo') 
        OR (`name` = 'Esther' AND `surname` = 'Smith');
```

Comment: As the list of names is large, isn't this very in-efficient?

Comment: Also, whith this approach, I don't know when there is no match for a certain combination (or I'd have to check that with a loop server side, which also takes time)

Comment: You could add to the SELECT the `name` and `surname` and verify which one was found. with that approach you reduce the queries to just one query. you would need to use loop on the server anyway since you are getting back array of id's.

Answer (score 0):

You may also try to concatenate the two parts and search like this:

```
SELECT id, CONCAT_WS(",", surname, name) AS FullName
FROM table1
HAVING FullName IN (
  "hand,bob", 
  "smith,steve", 
  "brown,rob", 
  "green,tom"
)
```

OR

```
SELECT id, CONCAT_WS(",", surname, name) AS FullName
FROM table1
WHERE CONCAT_WS(",", surname, name) IN (
  "hand,bob", 
  "smith,steve", 
  "brown,rob", 
  "green,tom"
)
```

Working fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2463e6

Comment: Does that approach still use the index on name?

Comment: @BastiaanWW I have not checked so can't say for sure. But I think it will not use index. If dataset is huge then you may try to do it in steps. Populate a new temporary table containing FullName, index the temp table on FullName, and then run the above query.